# Conversion of LocalDate to Oracle DATE uses timezone

Tags: java, hibernate, timezone

I'm Using the timezone 'America/Asuncion'.
There we have DST of 1 hour.

My solution is using Hibernate version 5.4.6

The database Oracle 12g is using the timezone.
In java, hibernate has the hibernate.jdbc.time_zone parameter.

In all tables that i have a DATE field, mapped to a LocalDate field of the mapping class, it has a problem for the [DTS changing dates](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/paraguay/asuncion).

For example (mm/dd/yyyy):

- 10/01/2017
- 10/07/2018

When the date is saved, it adds 1 hour to the date field:

- 10/01/2017 01:00:00
- 10/07/2018 01:00:00

That only happens on the specific dates of DST changes.

Any solution ? is this a know hibernate bug ?